# Trouble limiting bounds of movement for keyboard controlled sprite in java

Tags: java, collision-detection, arrow-keys

I have a Graphics image that I've coded to move when I press the keyboard arrow keys. I want it to only move if it is within a certain area of the GUI.

What I've tried:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_UP && y > 42)
    {
        up();
    }
}
```

The integer "y" is the y coordinate of the image. I thought if this condition was not satisfied, up() would not be called. This sort of worked, but only if I released the up key within the restricted area where y < 42. If I then tried to use the up arrow the image would not move. However, if I 
held the up arrow without releasing it, it would simply phase through the boundary.

I'm pretty sure I know the problem: Once I'm inside the if statement, the code won't recheck the conditions every time the sprite moves a pixel. It will only check once I release the key and press it again. Just don't know how to fix this. (I'm pretty sure the answer lies with collision detection, but I don't know)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Swap the order of checks (`y` first, key event second). Also consider using the Key Bindings API over `KeyListener` - it solves all the focus related issues

Comment: so if(y>42 && key==KeyEvent.VK_UP)? Don't see why that would work. I tried it, and it didn't.

Comment: Because Java can short circuit the `if` statement - but I can't remember exactly under what conditions - consider providing a [mcve] to remove the guess work and provide better context too your question and improve the chances and quality of the answers

Comment: I considered key bindings- it just seems a lot more complex.

Comment: They're actually a lot easier, simpler, more de-coupled and re-usable and solve the most annoying of `KeyListener` issues - they are simply, more reliable

Comment: Alright I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't y be less than 42 if you want to prevent movement beyond that point? Your if statement only executes if up arrow is pressed and y > 42.

Comment: Please rephrase this decent (though a little speculative) answer in order to sound less like a question. Because, you know, you should not use answer instead of comments. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead